# Synonymize [spam], [spam-prevention], [spam-blocking], [spam-filtering], [spam-detection], [spamming], and [antispam]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

These tags are all essentially the same concept.  As such, [spam-prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam-prevention) (392 questions, 23 followers), [spam-blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam-blocking) (52 questions, 6 followers), [spam-filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam-filtering) (112 questions, 10 followers), [spam-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam-detection) (4 questions, 0 followers), [spamming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spamming) (11 questions, 0 followers) and [antispam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antispam) (37 questions, 4 followers) should be synonymized.  The target should be [spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam) (731 questions, 11 followers).

To start off, [spamming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spamming) and [spam-prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam-prevention) mean the same thing, as per the wiki.

[spamming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spamming):

> For questions relating to the prevention of inbound or outbound spam.

[spam-prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam-prevention):

> Question context is related to spam prevention/filtering

Then, [spam-filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam-filtering) and [spam-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam-detection) match [spam-prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam-prevention) (their names match the contents of the wiki, and they represent the same concept)

Though not directly related wikiwise, [spam-blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam-blocking) is a synonym of [spam-prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam-prevention) from question contents and name.

Finally, [antispam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antispam) seems to be used as a synonym for the above.  Unless it is a product's name being used incorrectly, it should be synonymized as well (and it doesn't appear to be a product name from a quick search).

Putting these all into [spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam) makes the most sense as the concepts all fit.  The excerpt for [spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam) would probably need to be updated to include the concept of the use for the tag rather than just defining spam, though.

To summarize my request:

Synonymize the following to [spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam):

- [spam-prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam-prevention)
- [spam-blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam-blocking)
- [spam-filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam-filtering)
- [spam-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam-detection)
- [spamming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spamming)
- [antispam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antispam)

Comment: If we wanted to help spammers spamming, you wouldn't have a case ;-)

Comment: I think there are two tags here: mail-filtering (that includes spam) and spam-detection (that would mark mail as to be filtered)

Comment: What about questions relating to the [canned pre-cooked meat product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_(food))?

Comment: Reading this post reminded me of the Monty Python skit, lol.

Comment: @JohnOdom Well, the term "spam" comes from that very sketch so no wonder :)

Comment: @JohnOdom Reading your comment reminded me of Python programming language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've gone ahead and merged/synonymized all the tags into [spam-prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam-prevention) **except** for the [spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam) tag itself. Simply because browsing through the first page of questions there, I quickly ran across [this question which is a *result* of spam but had nothing to do with spam itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273430/final-touches-cleaning-mediawiki-tables-after-removing-spam-pages) and [this question about mail not being delivered which just plain isn't on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296923/sending-multiple-e-mails-with-php-mail-succesfully-but-they-dont-arrive-in) within the first five results. I think the [spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam) tag itself could use some manual clean-up before it gets synonymized into anything.