# Should we burninate the [spam] tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, spam

For context, the tag description for [spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam) says:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG ON QUESTIONS THAT ARE SPAM, we have a special flag for that! Questions about bypassing somebody else's spam filter are also not welcome. And keep in mind that this is a programming Q&A site, not a general computer support site. Spam is the use/abuse of electronic messaging systems (e.g. e-mail) to send unsolicited bulk messages indiscriminately.

(If it matters, I have only seen one case of somebody abusing the tag for a question they thought was "spam." Turns out it wasn't spam according to SE's definition anyway.)

Attempting to answer the [criteria questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied, and is it unambiguous?**

   Sometimes describes the contents, but no, not ambiguous. The intention of the tag, according to the description, is to classify questions about email spam. At a quick glance, I see that there are several questions that are about Discord spam bots, walls of text, promotional/malicious webpage links, SMS spam, and other things not email-related.

   There are tags for [email-spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email-spam) and [spam-prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam-prevention) now too, so I think that even the ones that are about email spam (and on-topic) should be retagged.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   I guess it *can* be if it's about sending emails or preventing spam emails programatically. I find that several questions aren't really programming-related at all.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   Given that not everyone seems to agree on a definition of "spam," I don't think so.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   No. There are many different meanings of "spam." Email spam, SMS spam, unwanted promotional linking on webpages, high-frequency repeated text/actions, to name a few. The questions reflect this.

I think we should burninate the tag, and perhaps a few more tags can be created to clarify what kind of spam is being talked about.

Comment: But how will then spammers tag their questions?

Comment: I understand we have the workforce to burn any tag(a while back, it was near impossible). But if the tag isn't attracting offtopic questions, why bother? *few more tags can be created to clarify what kind of spam* Why create these branch tags referring to the same concept? Volume of questions doesn't justify dividing this tag. Furthermore, there are already branches [spam-prevention], [email-spam]. If we should be doing anything, we should be synonymizing/merging not creating new branch tags just because burning is easy nowadays.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356057/  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278718/ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418914 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400136/decision-criteria-for-granting-rejecting-requests-about-combined-split-tags

Comment: Aw, dang. I just saw this one too: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278673/... I swear I searched through Meta for anything related...

Comment: @TheMaster I'm not sure what you mean by "same concept." Do you disagree with my assessment on question 4? Or are you saying that the tag guidance should be edited to encompass a wider scope?

Comment: `No. There are many different meanings of "spam."` Did you mean, "Yes, but there are different subdivisions of "spam""? Is "Email spam" spam? Is "SMS spam" spam? Is "unwanted promotional linking on webpages" spam? Do you really want to create all those different branch tags, as they're "different concepts" spam-email, spam-sms, spam-websites? I'm strongly against creating such tags.

Comment: We're on the same page with not creating new tags. I'm wondering about the "common meaning" you're applying here. I don't see one that captures all of them.

Comment: Ah, terrible reading comprehension. The tag guidance clearly applies to more than just email. I have no idea why I read it as exclusively email spam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I disagree. [spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spam) is actually useful. Majority of the questions are using this tag correctly, by asking how to make bots to spam comments messages etc. For discord or others. Other questions ask about how to prevent spam and detect it.

Plus, this seems on topic for SO as the users require code to perform the above.

Comment: You know, now that I read it again, I see the how the tag guidance applies to the other questions too. Argh, why can't I read things right the first time? Does leaving this question up have any merit even as a signpost? I'll gladly delete it if it doesn't and I'm still able do it.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance Don't delete it. If someone else want to burn it later, when they search, these discussions will be relevant.